# Java Hashtable<Object, Someclass>, if the key is string? if the string is same, it will remove all value with the same string

Tags: java, string, hashtable, equals, hashcode

I need a value of Someclass based on the key. And the key can be a string, boolean, or another Object, that's why I used  Object as key. But I have a problem, when the object is a string. and I have two Object of string, which is equals, but it should return different value, because it is a different object.

The code that I have:

```
Object k = new String("action");
Object l = new String("action");
Hashtable<Object,SomeClass> map = new Hashtable<Object, SomeClass>();

map.put(k,anObject1);
map.put(l,anObject2);

map.remove(k); // it is removing both with k and l.
```

when I check the hashCode() of both object, it returns the same value, which is ultimately what not I want.

Is there any solution of this? Is I need to make a new class that override Equals() of object? but, still, the hashCode. :( The problem is I need a hashCode that return different value for different Object.

Edited:
I am doing this because I need to do different action based on what the string is, but the action will differ by the value returned by map with the key.

Updated:
Okay, here is all the story why I need this weird thing.

I have a player instance, and 3 land instances. So I wanted the player to plow land1, land2, land3. If the player wanted to plow a land, that land make a running thread, that tell the player to move to position `X`, and do the job `action`, and `wait()` by object `action`, and when the other thread `notify` this thread by object `action`, the land then modify itself. The player then make an animation based on the object `action`. I am having `ArrayList<Position> destination` and 'ArrayList action` to have it. Maybe you can read my other question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581548/java-multi-threading-make-a-thread-wait-for-another-thread-or-joining-different/5582118#5582118).

So I wanted to make the action cancelable. I implements it by also passing the `action` object. I have a button that show for every action, and every button will cancel that action. I passing the `action` here too. So when I click the button, the land will get the `notify`. The problem is I can't make the `ArrayList<Position>` remove the destination by the `Action`, because it's don't know where the index. I'm new to Java but have been using C++ a lot, so I thinking of using Hashtables, because it's O(1) differs with C++ O(log n), and kind of convenience because not many changes to my current code.

Is it understandable?

Comment: "when I check the hashCode() of both object, it returns the same value."  Yes, that is *precisely* what a hash code (and by extension, a Hashtable/HashMap) is **for**.  Why is it you want two "different" keys to occupy two slots even though they represent the *exact same string*?

Comment: You might want to look into multimaps.

Comment: @Kirk Woll Because they are different object. I need to do different action based on what the string is, but the action will differ by the value. It is kind of that. I still can't think another algorithm.

Comment: @dieend: I don't really understand what you're saying there. Could you edit the question with a more complete explanation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @dieend, full stop -- if you need to do two different actions based on two different *instances* of a `String` object that both represent the exact same sequence of characters, then you need to take a big step back and reconsider.  You should not be doing that.

Comment: @Kirk Woll yep, that's what I meant. my bad. err, why should not? :(

Comment: @dieend, I'd like to turn that question around to you.  The strings are the same -- why do you want the different behavior?  Can you explain a little more what your real use-case is?

Comment: I've updated it. Is it understandable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [IdentityHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) instead, though it might help if you could explain what exactly you're trying to do here. This is not a terribly common requirement and unless you have some very good reasons you want to do this, there's probably something else you're better off doing.

By the way, a `Map` can only hold one value for a single key. So after your second call to `map.put`, the first value you put in there is already gone.

**Edit:**

Ok, I've read your explanation and... well, I'm still not completely clear on what you're doing. Here's my best guess from what you've said:

- You have an action called "plow", represented as a `String`.
- You are telling the player to "plow" 3 different lands.
- You want to be able to cancel that action for one land without cancelling it for the others.
- To do this, you're trying to map 3 different instances of the `String` "plow" to the `Position`s of the 3 different lands.

If this (or something like it) is what you're trying to do, here are my thoughts:

- The action `String` should not be unique... "plow" is "plow", whatever land it is done on. What *is* unique is the combination of an action like "plow" and the land that action is to be done on.
- Given that, "plow" should be considered something like an "action type". It might be good to use an `enum` or some such to represent action types.
- An `Action` class should contain an "action type" and a `Position`. When you click to cancel that `Action`, you have the data you need right there.

Comment: You might still end up with issues with String, if any interned Strings end up being used as keys

Comment: @Justin: Yes, though that's not possible if you're using `new String(...)` to create each key.

Comment: @dieend: Please note the caveats. It _does_ work, but you _probably_ shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @ColinD why I shouldn't doing this? @Kirk Woll saying the same thing.

Comment: @dieend: Because two `String` objects with the exact same characters should always be considered the same. They _are_ the same. You would need to hold on to references to these exact `String` objects you're using as keys in order to be able to retrieve the matching values, whereas normally any `String` object with the same characters should work. If you're going to break this, there has to be a _really good_ reason, but you haven't explained that at all. If you explained the whole context, I'm almost certain I'd recommend something else.

Answer (score 2):

The String class overrides equals() and hashCode() such that two Strings with the same characters have the same hashCode() and are equal. But the Object class itself has an equals() method that *never* returns true for two different objects. It's actually not necessary (nor possible!) for hashcodes to be unique; they just have to be nicely distributed across the range of possible values.

So in any case: String is ill-suited for your requirements, I agree; but an object of any other class that doesn't override equals() and hashCode()  should be just fine.

Comment: So if I make a new class it should be okay? I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the very semantics for a Hashmap: keys are uniqe and each value from the key domain maps to **at most** one value in the Hashmap.

Think of it like an array, only that the array is not indexed by numbers but by arbitrary objects. You can't have more than one different value at the same index in an array.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted the object differs, because it is different object, even if it is same string, so it should not happen.

Comment: Programming, in particular using APIs is not about *wanting* something. If I want the result of 2+2 not to be 4 I better look for another job - perhaps magician or medicine man.

Comment: maybe you misunderstand my question. Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating your own class to represent a Key and define your own hashcode by some unique identifier .. perhaps using a AtomicLong

Comment: I think it is dangerous to make own hashCode. And it is not that easy. sory